# Apache camel nested routes

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am new to Apache camel. I have very common use case that i am struggling to configure camel route. The use case is to take execution context

1. Update database using execution context.
2. Then using event on the execution context, create a byte message and send over MQ.
3. Then in the next step again use execution context and perform event processing.
4. Update database using execution context.

So basically its kind of nested routes. In the below configuration I need to have access to the executionContext that executionController has created in the updateSchedulerState, sendNotification, processEvent and updateSchedulerState i.e. steps annotated as 1,2, 3 and 4 respectively.

```
from("direct:processMessage")
    .routeId("MessageExecutionRoute")
    .beanRef("executionController", "getEvent", true)
    .beanRef("executionController", "updateSchedulerState", true)    (1)
    .beanRef("executionController", "sendNotification", true)        (2)
                 .beanRef("messageTransformer", "transform", true)       
                 .to("wmq:NOTIFICATION")
    .beanRef("executionController", "processEvent", true)            (3)
                 .beanRef("eventProcessor", "process", true)
                 .beanRef("messageTransformer", "transform", true)       
                 .to("wmq:EVENT")
    .beanRef("executionController", "updateSchedulerState", true);   (4)
```

Kindly let me know how should i configure the route for the above use case.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to access this `executionContext` in your beans at various points in the route?

If I understand correctly, you can put this executionContext in an exchange `Property`, and it will persist throughout the route.

Setting the exchange property can be done via the `Exchange.setProperty()` method or various camel dsl functions such as like this:

```
from("direct:xyz)
    .setProperty("awesome", constant("YES"))
    //...
```

You can access exchange properties from a bean by adding a method argument of type `Exchange`, like this:

```
public class MyBean {
    public void foo(Something something, Exchange exchange) {
        if ("YES".equals(exchange.getProperty("awesome"))) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or via `@Property` like this:

```
public class MyBean {
    public void foo(Something something, @Property String awesome) {
        if ("YES".equals(awesome)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

This presumes you are using later versions of camel.

Does this help?